# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to start wordpress remotely on a windows server 2008 R2 that has installed Apache web server 2.4 (i worked on wamp) and the port number is not 80 is 8888 (I heard that wordpress doesn't run on port 8888 maybe I'm wrong).When i start it throgh the browser i get this message "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.".Wamp has mysql buid in it but apache web server 2.4 doesn't, I checked the php_mysql.dll on php.ini and was uncommented, i queried mysql on command prompt and was fine.Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue like this on a windows install and it was down to this.

If you don't have the extension_dir uncommented on you php.ini, it wont default to the 'ext' directory (which is where all extension dlls are on windows).

Therefore, even uncommented extensions are ignored (and you wont see them on your phpinfo())
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php